# There exists a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[V]^G$ such that $f|_{O_1} = 0$ and $f|_{O_2} = 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

What is this following theorem? Does it have a name? Can somebody provide a reference? It arose in my algebra class today in vague passing.

> Let $G \to GL(V)$ be a finite-dimensional continuous representation of a compact group $G$. Prove that $G$-invariant polynomials on $V$ separate $G$-orbits in $V$; specifically, for any pair $O_1, O_2 \subset V$, of $G$-orbits such that $O_1 \neq O_2$, there exists a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{C}[V]^G$ such that $f|_{O_1} = 0$ and $f|_{O_2} = 1$.

Comment: The statement reminds me Urysohn lemma. (Though it might be irrelevant.)

Comment: Doesn't this statement even follow from Urysohn's Lemma?

Comment: You have to assume that the orbits are **disjoint**, not just distinct. Here is a proof of a very similar theorem: http://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/drutu/tcc2/onishchik-vinberg.pdf (page 133, Theorem 3). This is often called "separation of orbits".

Comment: Distinct orbits are disjoint.

Comment: @M.U. I expect Fredrik Meyer means you need $\overline{O_1}\cap\overline{O_2}=\emptyset$

Comment: But the orbit of a compact group is also compact.